# Disabling the button of an anchor tag

Tags: javascript, html

I have a button inside the anchor tag(defined it using class).

```
<a id="moreButton" class="contactButtonSmall" style="position:absolute; left:225px; top:165px;  FONT-WEIGHT:normal; FONT-SIZE:11pt;" onclick="doSomething();">More</a>
```

Now I want to disable it.So I have used the following code to disable the anchor tag.

```
moreButton.disabled = true;
```

The anchor tag is not working after disabling it , but the button of anchor still looks as if it is not disabled i.e. not grayed out. Is there any way to disable the button? Please let me know if you need any additional information.

Comment: firstly) inline css/js is bad practice that may lead to hard-to maintain code and other annoyances down the line. Secondly) why not disable the tag and just add css to grey it out?

Comment: @Turnip Sorry I didn't see the code

Comment: You can not disable an `<a>` tag in this way. The disabled attribute is for the `<button>` element, which you are not using.

Comment: just following up- has any solution been found? :)

Comment: @treyBake I have added the answer. Please take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used `button` along with the style attributes

```
background-color: Transparent;
    border: none;
```

instead of anchor tag to fix the issue. The style attributes helped to remove the grayed out area of the original html button and to keep my own image for the button.

example code is given below:

```
<button> id="moreButton" class="contactButtonSmall" style="position:absolute; left:225px; top:165px;  FONT-WEIGHT:normal; FONT-SIZE:11pt; background-color: Transparent;border: none;" onclick="doSomething();">More</button>
```

In CSS  file:

```
.contactButtonSmall {
    position:relative;
    display: block; /* 'convert' <a> to <div> */
    width: 60px;
    max-height: 20px;
    padding-top: 2px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    background-position: center top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url(../contactImages/blankSmallButton.gif);
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    cursor:pointer;
    background-color: Transparent;
    border: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to disable an anchor tag is to give it the correct [pointer-events](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_pointer-events.asp) property. Here's a simple example how to disable the anchor tag with one simple CSS line:

```css
a {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://google.com">I am a disabled anchor tag</a>
```

Comment: That's not really what they're asking, they want to know how to style it so it doesn't look like an anchor.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, inline CSS is bad practice so you should export your style code to a separate CSS file, as so:

```
.contactButtonSmall {
  position:absolute;
  left:225px;
  top:165px; 
  font-weight:normal;
  font-size:11pt;
}
```

Then you can use the `:disabled` selector to change the appearance of the button when it is disabled:

```
.contactButtonSmall:disabled {
  /* Styling for disabled button */
}
```

Comment: The `a` tag has no `disabled` attribute so this would not work. http://jsfiddle.net/g27cLwd1/1/

Answer (score -1):

You can use a mixture of CSS and JS to accomplish this:

HTML:

```
<a href="/" id="myLink">
    click me!
</a>
```

CSS:

```
#myLink {
    background: red
}

a#myLink.disabledLink {
    background: grey;
    cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById("myLink").onclick = function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    this.className += " disabledLink";
}
```

[jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/4srupn3v/)

this on click prevents the default action of the anchor tag and assigns it a class. The class has css that makes the cursor show the `now-allowed` icon as well as changing background colour to grey.

Comment: to downvoted - lemme know what's wrong so I can improve my answer :)